# how can avoid a string based on regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

am trying to fetch a string which only has a digit in it (the regex I give), but its returning me the both of them.

```
string1 = '1234843847394645362'
string2 = 'this is what I have 1297643847381737345is a multi'
```

Regex used :

```
'\d{15,20}'
```

this gives me both the numbers from string1 and string2 .

Can we avoid getting the number from string2 ?

need help.

Comment: Change to `^\d{15,20}$`

Comment: See also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch

Comment: @pylearner can you clearify what u want? word consit of digit only or full line contains only digit?

Comment: full line consists of only digit

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex: `^\d{15,20}$`

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtJ4RK/35) here

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match the digits when followed by a newline use `\Z`

```
\A\d{15,20}\Z
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dGmnUW/1)